# Id превращается в null после того, как достаю объект из модели

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Есть 2 контроллера:

```
@GetMapping("/productUpdate")
    public String productUpdateGet(@RequestParam Long productId,
                                   Model model){
        Product productForUpdate = productService.findProductById(productId);
        System.out.println(productForUpdate.getId());
        System.out.println(productForUpdate.getProductStatus());
        model.addAttribute("productForUpdate", productForUpdate);

        return "productTemplates/productUpdate";
    }

    @PostMapping("/productUpdate")
    public String productUpdatePost(@ModelAttribute("productForUpdate") Product productForUpdate,
                                    @RequestParam ProductStatus productStatus,
                                    @RequestParam Long productID){
        System.out.println(productForUpdate.getId());
        System.out.println(productForUpdate.getProductStatus());
        return "redirect:/allProducts";
    }
```

Первый контроллер выводит в консоль и id и productStatus, а второй вместо id выводит null, productStatus остаётся прежним. То есть по какой-то причине, после того, как я достаю объект из @ModelAttribute его id сбрасывается в null. Пожалуйста, объясните почему это происходит и как это исправить.

Вот модель объекта

```
package com.example.mywms.Model;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Product extends BaseEntity{

    @NotBlank(message = "Поле не должно быть пустым")
    private String productName;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private ProductType productType;

    @NotBlank(message = "Поле не должно быть пустым")
    @Size(min = 10, max = 255, message = "Описание товара должно быть от 10 до 255 символов")
    private String productDescription;

    @Positive(message = "Цена товара не может быть меньше 0 или быть равной 0")
    private double productPrice;

    @PositiveOrZero(message = "Количесвто товара не может быть меньше 0")
    private int productStock;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private ProductStatus productStatus;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "product_delivery",
        joinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "product_id"),
        },
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "delivery_id")
    )
    private Set<Delivery> deliveriesProductIn = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Вот HTML код

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Изменить</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>
            Warehouse Management System
            <small>WMS</small>
        </h1>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a th:href="@{/}">Главная</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a th:href="@{/allProducts}">Просмотр товаров</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a th:href="@{/productsManage}">Менеджмент товаров</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <p>Тестовый проект с использование Java Spring Framework и шаблонизатора Thymeleaf</p>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <form th:method="POST" th:action="@{/productUpdate}" th:object="${productForUpdate}">
        <div class="form-row" >
            <label for="inputProductName">Название товара</label>
            <input type="text" th:field="*{productName}" class="form-control" id="inputProductName" placeholder="Название товара">
            <div class="valid-feedback" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('productName')}" th:errors="*{productName}"></div>
            <!--<div class="valid-feedback" th:text="${productNameErrors}"></div>-->
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <label for="inputProductDescription">Описание товара</label>
            <input type="text" th:field="*{productDescription}" class="form-control" id="inputProductDescription" placeholder="Описание товара">
            <div class="valid-feedback" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('productDescription')}" th:errors="*{productDescription}"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <label for="inputProductPrice">Цена товара</label>
            <input type="text" th:field="*{productPrice}" class="form-control" id="inputProductPrice" placeholder="Цена товара">
            <div class="valid-feedback" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('productPrice')}" th:errors="*{productPrice}"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <label for="inputProductStock">Количество товара</label>
            <input type="text" th:field="*{productStock}" class="form-control" id="inputProductStock" placeholder="Количество товара">
            <div class="valid-feedback" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('productStock')}" th:errors="*{productStock}"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <label for="productType">Тип товара</label>
            <select id="productType" th:field="*{productType}" class="form-control" name="productType">
                <option th:value="BEATING" selected>BEATING</option>
                <option th:value="CLOTHES">CLOTHES</option>
                <option th:value="JEWELRY">JEWELRY</option>
                <option th:value="FOOD">FOOD</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Обновить</button>
    </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Так id вроде базой данных генерируется. На этом этапе он и не известен.

Comment: Как понять? Я же в первом контроллере получаю продукт по его id (то есть id у него уже есть), помещаю в модель и во втором контроллере получаю этот же продукт, только с обнулённым id, но id то у него по факту есть, разве нет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы, видимо, неверно представляете себе логику работы аннотации `@ModelAttribute` и вообще `Thymeleaf`.

**Связи** между аннотацией `@ModelAttribute` и Вашим методом, который делает `model.addAttribute("productForUpdate", productForUpdate)`, **нет**.

Вы добавляете атрибут в объект `Model` для того, чтобы `Thymeleaf` его увидел и на этом конец. Затем, Ваш объект `productForUpdate` "хранится" на странице и вы можете обращаться ко всем его полям, в том числе и к ID.

Потом вы нажимете кнопку "Обновить" **И** вы отправляете на сервер только те поля, которые на этой HTML-странице использовали и ничего более. Так как вы не используете там ID, то и не будете его отправлять. Если хотите, чтобы Ваш ID отображался в контроллере то Вам тогда нужно и "хранить" его на странице (я в HTML не силён, но логику вы поняли — нужно его хранить НО скрыть)

```
<div class="container">
    <form th:action="@{/productUpdate}" th:method="POST" th:object="${productForUpdate}">
        <!--        HIDDEN ID/-->
        <label for="inputProductId" th:type="hidden"></label>
        <input type="text" th:field="*{id}" class="form-control" th:type="hidden" id="inputProductId"/>

        <div class="form-row" >
            <label for="inputProductName">Название товара</label>
            <input type="text" th:field="*{productName}" class="form-control" id="inputProductName" placeholder="Название товара">
            <div class="valid-feedback" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('productName')}" th:errors="*{productName}"></div>
            <!--<div class="valid-feedback" th:text="${productNameErrors}"></div>-->
        </div>
...
```

P.S. Я пишу "хранится" в кавычках потому что на самом деле никакие поля объекта на странице не хранятся, естественно. Если кратко, то логика работы `Thymeleaf` такая ->

1. Вы создаете HTML-страницу в которой используете шаблонизатор
2. Затем в контроллере добавляете в специальный объект `Model` объекты для заполнения этого шаблона.
3. Потом возвращаете в контроллере имя шаблона
4. Затем Spring всё это дело перехватывает и парсит вашу HTML-страницу вставляя в шаблонные места ваши данные из объекта `Model`
5. Возвращает уже **ГОТОВУЮ СТРАНИЦУ**.

Как вы уже поняли, на вашей страницу уже нет никаких объектов и ничего там больше не хранится. Ваша страница была обработана ещё на сервере. Поэтому если вы не используете на своей странице ID, то и взяться ему там НЕ-ОТ-КУ-ДА

P.S.S. Если хотите без таких "костылей", то используйте JavaScript и вручную всё это заполняйте. Там всё будет хранится :)

Comment: Здравствуйте, спасибо Вам большое за объяснение!