# Spring MVC пустая модель в PostMapping

Tags: java, spring, mvc

Проблема в следующем, у меня есть mapping для создания новой сущности, в нем я кладу новый новый объект в модель (который в веб форме наполняется). При отправке Post запроса на другой соответствующий mapping модель оказывается совершенно пустой, хотя по идее там должен лежать мой объект. Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/bid")
public class BannersController {

private final BannersDAO bannersDAO;

@Autowired
public BannersController(BannersDAO bannersDAO) {
    this.bannersDAO = bannersDAO;
}

@GetMapping("/banners")
public String bannersPage(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("banners", bannersDAO.getAll());
    return "banners/banners";
}

@GetMapping("/banners/new") 
public String newBannerPage(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("banner", new Banner()); // Вот я кладу объект
    model.addAttribute("banners", bannersDAO.getAll());
    return "banners/createBanner";
}

//Проблему с пустой моделью я обнаружил только для Post метода, с остальными все отлично
@PostMapping("/banners")
public String createBanner(Model model){
    System.out.println(model); // А в этом методе модель ничего не содержит(модель пустая, хотя должна содержать мой объект, который я впихнул ранее)
    model.getAttribute("banner"); // Возвращает null
    return "redirect:/bid/banners";
}

@GetMapping("/banners/{id}")
public String bannerByIdPage(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model){
    Banner banner = bannersDAO.getById(id);
    if(banner == null) return "redirect:/bid/banners";
    model.addAttribute("banner", banner);
    model.addAttribute("banners", bannersDAO.getAll());
    return "banners/banner";
}

@GetMapping("/banners/{id}/edit")
public String editBannerPage(Model model, @PathVariable("id") int id){
    Banner banner = bannersDAO.getById(id);
    if(banner == null) return "redirect:/bid/banners";
    model.addAttribute("banner", banner);
    model.addAttribute("banners", bannersDAO.getAll());
    return "banners/editBanner";
}

@PatchMapping("/banners/{id}")
public String updateBanner(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model){
    return "bid";
}
}
```

Представление Html + Thymeleaf

```html
<body>
<div class="container">
    <header class="header">
        <nav class="header__nav">
            <a href="/bid/banners" class="header__link header__link_active">Banners</a>
            <a href="/bid/categories" class="header__link">Categories</a>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <main class="main">
        <aside class="sidebar">
            <header class="sidebar__header">Banners:</header>

            <section class="sidebar__content">
                <div class="sidebar__search">
                    <input class="sidebar__search-input" type="text" placeholder="Enter banner name..." />
                    <span class="sidebar__search-icon"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="sidebar__menu" th:each="banner : ${banners}">
                    <a th:href="@{/bid/banners/{id}(id=${banner.getId()})}" class="sidebar__menu-item" th:text="${banner.getName()}"/>
                </div>
            </section>
        </aside>

        <section class="content">
            <div class="content__body">
                <div class="content__form" th:object="${banner}">
                    <div class="content__form-item">
                        <div class="content__form-item-title">Name</div>
                        <div class="content__form-item-content">
                            <input class="content__input" type="text" th:field="*{name}"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="content__form-item">
                        <div class="content__form-item-title">Price</div>
                        <div class="content__form-item-content">
                            <input class="content__input" type="text" th:field="*{price}"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="content__form-item">
                        <div class="content__form-item-title">Category</div>
                        <div class="content__form-item-content">
                            <input class="content__input" type="text" th:field="*{categories}"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="content__form-item">
                        <div class="content__form-item-title">Text</div>
                        <div class="content__form-item-content">
                            <textarea class="content__textarea" th:field="*{text}"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <form th:method="post" th:action="@{/bid/banners}">
                <footer class="content__footer">
                    <div class="content__buttons"   >
                        <button  class="content__button content__button_dark">Save</button>
                    </div>
                </footer>
            </form>
            <footer class="content__footer">
                <div class="content__buttons">
                    <button onclick="location.href='/bid/banners/new'" class="content__button content__button_red">Clear</button>
                </div>
            </footer>

<!--            <div class="error">-->
<!--                <span class="error__text">Banner with name "some banner" is already exist</span>-->
<!--            </div>-->
        </section>
    </main>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: не особо понял проблему, но model.addAttribute("banner", new Banner()); - тут создается пустой объект.  model.getAttribute("banner"); // null - тут вы получаете этот пустой объект new Banner().

Comment: model.getAttribute("banner");  - дело в том, что тут я получаю null, поскольку модель полностью пустая, там нет этого объекта

Comment: Тогда вопрос - а откуда вы ее получаете? get отправляет пустой объект,  но он по пути теряется, там и надо искать причину

Comment: я отредактировал вопрос, надеюсь, сейчас станет понятнее

Comment: <form th:method="post" th:action="@{/bid/banners}">
                <footer class="content__footer">
                    <div class="content__buttons"   >
                        <button  class="content__button content__button_dark">Save</button>
                    </div>
                </footer>
            </form> - ну как бы тут и нет никакого объекта, вот и null

Comment: так thymeleaf просто берет объект из модели (ссылку на него, сам объект по идее не удаляется из модели) и внедряет значения в поля. Состояние модели не меняется в ходе этих действий. Проблема в чем-то другом

Comment: в методе post thymeleaf у вас не прописан никакой объект.

Comment: Очень часто в последнее время вижу такие вопросы по Thymeleaf... Ребят, вы хоть документацию-то почитайте сначала и разберитесь как и что работает. Похожий вопрос - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1406954/id-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b2-null-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8e-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8/1407100#1407100

Comment: То, что Вы добавили свой объект в объект `Model` не имеет НИКАКОГО отношения к вашему контроллеру, где вы этот объект достаёте через `model.getAttribute("banner")`.

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.