# java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "?" because the return value of "?" is null

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Делаю заготовку интернет-магазина с использованием Spring Boot и Thymeleaf. В нем предполагается такой алгоритм:
При переходе на страницу товара, метод контроллера, возращающий страницу товара, сначала создает новый объект `Purchase` (Покупка), затем создает новый объект `Product` (Товар) и присваивает этот объект полю объекта `Purchase` и кладет объект `Purchase` в модель. Затем метод возвращает страницу товара. На странице товара пользователь выбирает количество товара и нажимает кнопку Купить и этот объект `Purchase` с формой отправляется обратно на сервер. Так вот при получении формы сервером поле `product` объекта `purchase` почему-то равно null и выдает следующую ошибку:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "ru.terentyev.playtoxapp.entities.Product.getStock()" because the return value of "ru.terentyev.playtoxapp.entities.Purchase.getProduct()" is null
```

Хотя, как я писал выше, я перед отправкой объекта в представление положил в его поле `product` объект.
Как исправить?

Метод контроллера, добавляющий составной объект в модель и возвращающий страницу товара:

```
    @GetMapping("/products/{id}")
    public String viewProduct(@PathVariable int id, Model model, @AuthenticationPrincipal PersonDetails personD) {
        Product product = productService.findById(id);
        model.addAttribute("product", product);
        Purchase purchase = new Purchase();
        purchase.setProduct(product);       
        if (personD != null) purchase.setOwner(personD.getPerson());
        model.addAttribute("purchase", purchase);
        return "viewProduct";
    }
```

Часть представления:

```
<div th:object="${product}">
    <h3 th:text="*{name}"></h3><br>
    <h5 th:text="|Цена: *{price}руб.|"></h5>
    <h5 th:text="|Остаток: *{stock}|"></h5>
    <span th:text="*{description}"></span><br><br>
    <form sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()" th:method="POST" th:action="@{/products/buy}" th:object="${purchase}">
        <span th:text="${purchase.product}"></span>
        <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('global')}">Вы выбрали больше, чем есть в наличии</span>
        <!--<input type="hidden" th:field="*{product}" th:value="${productOfPurchase}"/>-->
        <input type="number" placeholder="Кол-во для покупки" value="Количество" th:field="*{count}"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Купить"/>
        </form>
    <br><br><br>
    <a sec:authorize="hasRole('ADMIN')" th:href="@{/admin/products/{id}/edit(id=*{id})}">Изменить</a>
    
    
    </div>
```

Метод, принимающий post запрос с этим объектом, у которого поле почему-то равно null:

```
    @PostMapping("/products/buy")
    public String buy(@ModelAttribute Purchase purchase, BindingResult br) {
        if (purchase.getProduct().getStock() < purchase.getCount()) {
            br.addError(new ObjectError("globalError", "Вы выбрали кол-во товара большее, чем есть в наличии"));
            if (br.hasErrors()) return "redirect:/products/{id}".replace("{id}", String.valueOf(purchase.getProduct().getId()));
            return "viewProduct";
        }
        purchaseService.buy(purchase);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
```

Comment: Кажется, нашел ответ в этом вопросе: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1406954 . Оказывается Thymeleaf так работает, что надо присваивать значения полям именно в представлении, поскольку без этого они все сбрасываются на null, насколько я понял. Буду принимать этот post запрос с id товара через @PathVariable int id